# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' in ubuntu for installing mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

When i tried to install mysql by:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

In configuring phpmyadmin i got this error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
```

I tried

```
service mysql status
```

to see what's going on with my mysql and i got this:

```
 ● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
       Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: en
       Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2018-05-15 10:00:29 +0430; 25min
      Process: 1012 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exit

    مئی 15 10:00:29 Thispc-Lenovo-G50-80 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off t
    مئی 15 10:00:29 Thispc-Lenovo-G50-80 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart `enter code here`
    مئی 15 10:00:29 Thispc-Lenovo-G50-80 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
    مئی 15 10:00:29 Thispc-Lenovo-G50-80 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repe
    مئی 15 10:00:29 Thispc-Lenovo-G50-80 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result
    مئی 15 10:00:29 Thispc-Lenovo-G50-80 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community S
```

I see that it has errors but when i try to retstart mysql by

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

I get this error:

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

I searched and i found this command:

```
su - mysql -s /bin/sh -c "/usr/bin/mysqld_safe > /dev/null 2>&1 &"
```

and it asked for password and i entered my root password and get this error:

```
su: Authentication failure error
```

Then i tried to change my username and password by

```
mysql -h localhost -u root -p
```

and again i got the:

```
 ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' error
```

And i also tried

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

and

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

and got same 2002 error

As you can see i'm pretty messed up and i've been trying to make it work for almost two days.I'd be honored if someone could help me.

Comment: have you tried restart `sudo service mysql restart` ?

Comment: yeah and got error:
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Comment: _"Then i tried to change my username and password by `mysql -h localhost -u root -p`_" No, this is not the way to change password and user name

Answer (score 1):

This problem happened to me before and I solved it by follow this [article](https://www.zyxware.com/articles/5539/solved-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run-mysqld-mysqld-sock).

What I did was kill the `mysql` process before restart it.

Comment: Thanks for your help but i did kill it and unfortunately again got same error: Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Comment: and the systemctl status mysql.service still looks like what i copied for you above with an error in activation